# Ignore where in rank formula with Spring Data / Hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have a field with @Formula that use rank.

```kotlin
@Formula("rank() OVER(order by num_calls, last_name, name)")
var ranked: Long = 0
```

The problem is a need add where clause but the rank must be of all data, not only for filtered with where.

With standard sql, I could use a subquery as:

```sql
select * from (select name, rank() OVER(order by num_calls, last_name, name) from data) as t where name = 'Bob'
```

But, with Spring Data and QueryDSL I don't know how use.

I need dynamic a query  using querydsl.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, you will have to dig into [Blaze-Persistence](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#how-to-use-it), which works on top of JPA/Hibernate and has a [QueryDSL integration](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/core/manual/en_US/index.html#querydsl-integration). With these tools, you can create such queries. See https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/core/manual/en_US/index.html#subquery-joins